# Hyperlink two documents in ArcMap using VBscript when one might be "null"

Tags: arcmap, vbscript, hyperlink

I am an Ecologist that frequently dips into GIS work but I know next to nothing about script. I copied a script I found on this site and it ALMOST works for my application. I am hopeful its a quick/simple fix.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have 2 different document fields I am trying to hyperlink. The first one is named "FILE_NAME" and the second is "Survey_Doc". Sometimes both docs are present, but sometimes only one document is present (therefore, one field may be "null"). The code I found and adjusted for my use works flawlessly in opening both documents as long as both are present or if only the "FILE_NAME" doc is present. However, if "FILE_NAME" is "Null" but there is a "SurveyDoc", the hyperlink tool will not show a link is available to open in ArcMap Data View.So, I'm trying to figure out how to get it to open the "SurveyDoc" even when the "FILE_NAME" is blank/null.

Here is my script:

```
Function OpenLink ( [FILE_NAME] , [SurveyDoc]  )
  Dim path, path2
  Dim objShell
  path ="..\PDF\" +  [FILE_NAME]
  path2 = "..\PDF\" + [SurveyDoc]
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  objShell.ShellExecute path, "", "", "open", 1
  objShell.ShellExecute path2, "", "", "open", 1
End Function
```

Comment: My script formatting did not post correctly. I had to post it as a picture

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  I have rolled-back your edit and formatted your code.  For next time, there is a **`{}`** button on the editor which will format your code

Comment: Is your feature data, the one with the hyperlinks, a shapefile or geodatabase feature class? (shapfiles don't support Null so your *empty* value will be '', feature classes do support Null values but your population can be '' or DBNull) One simple fix is to populate all your empty filenames with a bland "Nothing to show here" then test for that value in your OpenLink function before trying to open your document.

Comment: It is a gdb feature class.

Comment: I think your execute fails if the path is not valid. Put in a conditional  if isNull statement before the path assignment or validate path before the objShell.ShellExecute  to check check if path is valid.